# Cannot deploy program to devnet with Anchor

Tags: smartcontracts, solana

On trying to deploy a program to devnet using anchor deploy, it takes a long while and throws the below error:
Data writes to account failed: There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

I tried downgrading both anchor and solana; it doesn't work.
On retrying, it goes into:
Blockhash expired. 5 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining
Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might actually be just a network error. I switched to a different network and since the devnet wallet is not working currently, deployed it on the testnet and it totally worked.

Note: I'd tried to deploy on testnet earlier (using my previous network) and still got the same error, so it's not a devnet issue. Switching to a different network is what got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps devnet was experiencing some issues at the time.  To try from scratch, please do the following:

- install the newest version of the CLI (1.8.5 as of this writing): https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#use-solanas-install-tool
- airdrop yourself enough SOL, say 10 to be safe, using `solana airdrop 1` multiple times
- make sure you're on devnet: `solana config set --url devnet`
- build the program to be sure: `cargo build-bpf`
- deploy the program: `solana program deploy path_to_my_built_program.so`

If you're still having issues after that, could you post your program's address? Then we can see the transactions that have succeeded and failed.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a devnet issue. I tried multiple times over the past few days. Same error. Built it from the scratch again with the above instructions; solana program deploy and anchor deploy don't work. Got through with anchor deploy --program-name <program ID> but it seems like a false positive as it doesn't show up in the explorer. 
Prog ID: 322UyGdq4VrLd6zKv3PFhhgmGQYnxS3XSirX52Vaxe64

Comment: Still getting the error: Data writes to account failed: HTTP status client error (408 Request Timeout) for url (https://api.devnet.solana.com/)

Comment: Try checking your local configs if they are correctly setup? `solana config get` ?

Comment: Config File: /home/sola/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.devnet.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/sola/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed